# Microsoft excel open high low close chart creation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a bunch of raw data that is ordered in a column with the first cell being the open, and the last cell being the close. is there a set of formulas I can use where it can sort the open high low close data for that set?

I want this

[image: this image]

To look like this

[image: To look like this]

Answer (score 2):

If im reading the question correctly your outcome shows 1267 in your low and close but i believe it should be 1239 for the 27th.

Open, high and low are array formulas and will need to hit **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** when you've finished typing.

[image]

**Open**

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$16,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$16,0))
```

**High**

```
=MAX(IF($A$3:$A$16=F2,$B$3:$B$16))
```

**Low**

```
=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$16=F2,$B$3:$B$16))
```

**Close**

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$16=F2),$B$2:$B$16)
```